# When one uses the "ACSII BEL" character i.e. '\a' in any programming language?

Tags: ascii

I stumbled upon fancy ASCII BEL in a book. Then I (Briefly) read the article on ASCII BEl on Wikipedia, and did know that it produces a noise(alert noise).

Tried in python(3), tried in C, didn't work.
Probably people don't need the bell these days or something.

Comment: It was there probably for historical reasons. No one really uses it now.

Comment: if you print the BEL on old linux shell it will actually beep. also old versions of Adobe Acrobat Reader will make a noise if the PDF contains a BEL. I have an old printer that certenly does beep when there is e BEL in the printed file. I however can´t tell How the BEL is handled in more recent software.
The character originates from the old telegraph era where you sent a BEL to signal a starting transmission to the listener on the other end

Comment: It does indeed work on Windows 10's command prompt.   
 `C:\>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("\a") # plays an alert tone`

Comment: @Nefrin I thought that too. Thank You for even more clarification.

Comment: @Horsey I am using not Windows 10. So probably I don't have the privilege.

Comment: Also note that some terminal emulators implement a *visual* bell, where they "flash" the window instead of playing a sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is seldom in use now and many consoles are not supporting it. In case you are interested in the history of it, I found this from Microsoft:

> A long time ago, all PC computers shared a common 8254 programable interval timer chip for the generation of primitive sounds. The Beep function was written specifically to emit a beep on that piece of hardware.
>
> On these older systems, muting and volume controls have no effect on Beep; you would still hear the tone. To silence the tone, you used the following commands:
>
> ```
> net stop beep
> sc config beep start= disabled
> ```
>
> Since then, sound cards have become standard equipment on almost all PC computers. As sound cards became more common, manufacturers began to remove the old timer chip from computers. The chips were also excluded from the design of server computers. The result is that Beep did not work on all computers without the chip. This was okay because most developers had moved on to calling the MessageBeep function that uses whatever is the default sound device instead of the 8254 chip.
>
> Eventually because of the lack of hardware to communicate with, support for Beep was dropped in Windows Vista and Windows XP 64-Bit Edition.

Comment: Finally now I can explain this thing to myself and probably others. One thing I didn't get is, why the sound card manufacturers didn't implement the '\a'? It would have been 'vintage' thing.

Comment: Yes, but they don't have to. They just moved on to use the default sound from the sound card instead of implementing the "beep". So my speculation was probably right. It was there for historical reaons, and perhaps, for backwards compatibility. I don't know which year you were borned in, but I have used those early 90s computers before when I was a kid. All sound came from the chip. I remember hitting the keyboard endlessly will trigger a continuous flow of beeps.

Comment: **borned** = born. I was born in '97, didn't get to use computers till 2015 or something. It would have been great to use both technology; older and modern.